# How to reuse fragment's view in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a Fragment Activity with tabs. Now whenever i select a tab, corresponding fragment gets recreated and its

```
onCreateView()
```

method is called.
But what i want is to reuse the view of the fragment so that whenever a tab is selected system does not call

```
onCreateView()
```

of fragment instead it shows the previous view of the fragment if it exists.
Please reply soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setOffScreenPageLimit() method can be used to set how many fragments you want to keep alive even if they are not visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to show and hide the fragments instead of adding and removing them when selecting a tab.

For example:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if (frag.isAdded()) {
    transaction.show(R.id.layout, frag);
} else {
    transaction.add(R.id.layout, frag);
}
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for screen rotation and should work for your situation as well:

1) When you add fragment for the first time, create it with name parameter:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(<containerID>, <fragment>, YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME_CONST)
    .commit();
```

2) When you need to find it:

```
YourFragmentType fragment;
fragment = (YourFragmentType) getSupportFragmentManager()
  .findFragmentByTag(YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME_CONST);

if (fragment != null){
//TODO set data to the existing fragment
}
else{
//TODO create and initialize your fragment 
}
```

**Edit**:
You should **differentiate** Fragment *object creation* and *onCreateView()* being called.

It's right that you should avoid unnecessary object creation and so **reuse** fragments.
On the other hand (as for my experience) it's better to **adhere** Android's onCreateView() politics to guarantee consistent user experience.

If you really want to save CPU time and avoid re-inflating complicated view (and settle all issues yourselves) - you may just check it is null like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // View
        if (mView == null) {
            mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
            ...
        }    
...
    }
```

Comment: setOffScreenPageLimit() on viewPager worked for me. As per your answer, the onCreateView() method of fragment is called everytime.